# Postgres Crosstab query Dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

Does any one know how to create the following crosstab in Postgres?

For example I have the following table:

```
Store      Month        Sales
A          Mar-2020     100
A          Feb-2020     200
B          Mar-2020     400
B          Feb-2020     500
A          Jan-2020     400
C          Apr-2020     600
```

I would like the query to return the following crosstab, the column headings should not be hardcoded values but reflect the values in "month" column from the first table:

```
Store    Jan-2020    Feb-2020    Mar-2020    Apr-2020
A        400         200         100         -
B        -           500         400         -
C        -           -           -           600
```

Is this possible?

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: Wanted to emphasize that my goal is to dynamically pull out the column headers from the first table and not hardcode them since the data will change every month. Is this possible?

Comment: No, not possible. The number, type and name of the columns of a query must be known to the database **before** the query is even started

Comment: Thank you. Slightly tangential but do you know if it is possible to alias a column to be a date? for example select sum(this_month.sales) as DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date)? My example here does not work but wanted to see if there was another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres does have a `crosstab` function, but I think using the built in filtering functionality is simple in this case:

```
select store,
       sum(sales) filter (where month = 'Jan-2020') as Jan_2020,
       sum(sales) filter (where month = 'Feb-2020') as Feb_2020,
       sum(sales) filter (where month = 'Mar-2020') as Mar_2020,
       sum(sales) filter (where month = 'Apr-2020') as Apr_2020
from t
group by store
order by store;
```

Note:  This puts `NULL` values in the columns with no corresponding value, rather than `-`.  If you really wanted a hyphen, you would need to convert the value to a string -- and that seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to pull the column headers from the data instead of hard coding them in? My table is just an example but will contain the last N months of sales so this data will change every month.  For example next month will contain May-2020 and its not feasible to edit the query once a month.

Comment: @user2491463 . . . That requires a dynamic pivot and some sort of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `CASE` expression inside `SUM()`, here is the [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/691qLQ8e8h8RbDQFVALoDk/0).

```
select
    store,
    sum(case when month = 'Jan-2020' then sales end) as "Jan-2020",
    sum(case when month = 'Feb-2020' then sales end) as "Feb-2020",
    sum(case when month = 'Mar-2020' then sales end) as "Mar-2020",
    sum(case when month = 'Apr-2020' then sales end) as "Apr-2020"
from myTable
group by
   store
order by
   store
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|store  Jan-2020    Feb-2020    Mar-2020    Apr-2020|
+---------------------------------------------------+
| A        400         200         100         null |
| B        null        500         400         null |
| C        null        null        null        600  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want to replace `null` values with `0` in the output then use `coalesce()`

*e.g.*

```
coalesce(sum(case when month = 'Jan-2020' then sales end), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to pull the column headers from the data instead of hard coding them in? My table is just an example but will contain the last N months of sales so this data will change every month.  For example next month will contain May-2020 and its not feasible to edit the query once a month.